# Hair works in viewport, but won't be rendered

Tags: hair

I have this blend file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zj42em9ia5fa91s/running_mixamo_animated_hair.blend?dl=0

and it works in viewport and i can successfully render the viewport animation.

[image]

However whenever i try to render this, it simply does not work. It renders this:

[image]

my settings:

[image]

[image]

maybe it is important: i use multiple cameras (although i don't believe this causes the problem)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Blender version do you use? If I open it in 2.92 there is no visible hair in the viewport. I have to clear the cache and switch the type from hair to emitter and back to hair. Then it's displayed... (?)

Comment: thanks Blunder. it happened in 2.92, 3.0.0alpha and 2.93. For me it looks like the hair "thing" is pretty unstable because although i did this what you said and cleared cache...only sometimes it worked. But more often it just showed no hair. And often Blender crashed. :( As i said - i see hair in the viewport, but not when rendering